# How to store articles in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store the articles which are submitted by my website users.

1.The articles will be 100 to 200 lines in length.

2.The articles will have html tags.For example:

```
"<br>"
```

Tell me which "TYPE" should i select when creating the Column in the MYSQL Database and tell me the "LENGTH" too.

I tried VARCHAR but it is not working.

Comment: Why would you need to insert `<br />` tags in your database, PHP does that with `\n` by itself.

Comment: "Not working" is not an explanation of the problem you are facing. Give us more details so we can understand your problem.

Comment: @phpNoOb It only does that if you run [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) on the text containing `\n`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use TEXT or MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT column types

TEXT column can store 65,535 characters
MEDIUMTEXT can store 16,777,215 characters
LONGTEXT can store 4,294,967,295 characters

Please note that, if characters are multi-byte characters (like UTF-8), then these numbers are less.

Answer (score 6):

use `TEXT` type  when storing long text.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having users input HTML text, rather let them use markdown syntax. Something similar to what SO provides.

You can store them in `TEXT` type field and later use client side scripts to parse them as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `TEXT` or `MEDIUMTEXT`or `LONGTEXT`

see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html